# How to mongoexport and mongoimport collections with new ids but keeping the relation

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongoexport

I export 2 collections using mongoexport:

```
mongoexport -h -u -p --db dev -c parent -q '{_id: ObjectId("5ae1b4b93b131f57b33b8d11")}' -o parent.json
```

and

```
mongoexport -h -u -p --db dev -c children -q '{parentId: ObjectId("5ae1b4b93b131f57b33b8d11")}' -o children.json
```

From the first one I got one record (selected by ID) and from the second I got many record (selected by parentId which is ID from the first one.

How can I use mongoimport to import those with new IDs but keeping the relation -> `parent.id = child.parentId`

?

Comment: What are you expecting? Nested JSON with arrays of the related children? What is the purpose and why can you not simply export the two collections separately?

Comment: @NeilLunn The purpose is to clone 1 document from 1 collection and a few from 2nd collection which are related to the first one. The question is not about export but import - the export is correct. I expected clone of the parent in the same collection and clones of children in another but with objectId pointed on the parent.

Comment: Sorry, was responding to what I thought was a different question. I asked you the purpose because I wanted to understand what you wanted this for. I still don't because you have not really explained. As for "why it does not do this", is simply because MongoDB itself does not know anything about "relations". The relation is a "client concept", and just because you used the same value in different fields is no reason for that to automatically happen.

Comment: Point being you are either A.. Trying to export related data to an external system. B. Trying to move between collections/instances with MongoDB but not understanding from from the server point of view there is no relation here. If you can explain your intent in the question, then we can guide you to the correct action. But what you are "expecting" just does not happen.

Comment: Partly agree, however ObjectId is sth more than "value", because it pointed on other doc. The question is if it is possible to export part of collections (-q flag) and it is possible to import with insert --mode in which you get new objectIds, the translation of other objectId is possible (at least theoretically) based on translation table, to sum up - is it possible?

Comment: The intent is simple: export parent doc from 1 collection with many related docs from others (based on objectid) and clone them to the same collections with new objectIds but with binding between them kept.

Comment: You may think it's "simple" however you still appear to be missing a few core concepts. The answer should straighten those out for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; Skip to the parts to solve this, or actually read if you want to clear up the misconception.

### Background

Let's clear up the basic misconception here in that MongoDB *"itself"* has ***no concept of relations, whatsoever***. A "relation" as you are referring to it merely a value recorded in the property in one collection which *"refers"* to another value present in a different collection. Nothing about these *"foreign keys"* enforces any kind on constraint in MongoDB which defines that the data is *"related"*, and they are just *"values"*.

Once you accept that fact then it should be self apparent why any tool such as [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) or even basic query operations like [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) really have no idea that just because you put a value in somewhere that it is *"meant to"* go and get that data from somewhere else.

Once upon a time there was ( and it sill is to a lesser extent ) a concept called [`DBRef`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs), which stored not just a "value" but also some detail as to where that value resided in a "referential" term. This could be collection or database and collection. The concept however remains relatively short lived and not useful in modern context. Even with this "metadata" stored, the database itself covered no concept of "relation" to the data. Retrieval still remained a "client concept" where some drivers had the ability to see a [`DBRef`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbrefs) and then "resolve" it by issuing another query to the server to retrieve the "related" data.

Naturally this is "full of holes" and the concept was abandoned in favor of more modern concepts, notably [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

### Modern Construction

What this all really comes down to is that as far as MongoDB itself is concerned a "relation" is actually ***"client concept"***, in the sense that an "external entity" actually makes the decision that "this" is related to "that" via what data you define as "equal references".

There are no "database rules" that enforce this, so in contrast to various traditional RDBMS solutions, the "object store" nature of MongoDB essentially says *"...that's not my job, delegate to someone else"* and that typically means you define that within the "client" logic of what is used to access the database.

However, there are *"some tools"* that allow the "server" to actually act on that logic. These essentially revolve around [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which is essentially he "modern method" to perform "joins" on the server when working with MongoDB.

So if you have "related data" you want to "export", then you basically have a couple of options:

- #### Create a "view" using $lookup

  MongoDB introduced ["views"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) with the 3.2 release. These are essentially "aggregation pipelines" which *"masquerade"* as a collection. For all purposes of normal operations like `.find()` or even `mongoexport` this pipeline looks just like a collection and can be accessed as such.

  ```
  db.createView("related_view", "parent", [
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": "children",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "parentId",
      "as": "children"
    }}
  ])
  ```

  With that "view" in place you can simply call `mongoexport` using the name defined for the "view":

  ```
  mongoexport -c related_view -o output.json
  ```

  Just as [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) will do, each "parent" item will now contain an array with the "related" content from "children" by the foreign key.

  As [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) produces the output as a BSON Document, the same constraints apply as with all MongoDB in that the resulting "join" cannot exceed 16MB within any document. So if the array causes the parent document to grow beyond this limit then using output as an "array" embedded within the document is not an option.

  For this case you would generally use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in order to "de-normalize" the output content just as it would appear with a typical SQL join. In this case the "parent" document would be copied for each "related" member, and output documents match those from the related children but with all the parent information and the "children" as a singular embedded property.

  This just means adding [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to such a "view":

  ```
  db.createView("related_view", "parent", [
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": "children",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "parentId",
      "as": "children"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$children" }
  ])
  ```

  Since we are just outputting essentially one document for each "related child" then it's unlikely the BSON Limit is breached. With very large documents for both parent and child it is still a possibility, though rare. For that case there would be different handling as we can mention later.
- #### Use $lookup directly in script

  If you don't have a MongoDB version supporting "views" but you still have [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and no restriction of the BSON Limit, you could still essentially "script" the invocation of the aggregation pipeline with the `mongo` shell and output as JSON.

  The process is similar yet instead of using a "view" and `mongoexport`, we manually wrap a few commands which can be invoked into the shell from the command line:

  ```
  mongo --quiet --eval '
      db.parent.aggregate([ 
        { "$lookup": {
          "from": "children",
          "localField": "_id",
          "foreignField": "parentId",
          "as": "children"
        }}
      ]).forEach(p => printjson(p))'
  ```

  And again much the same as the process before you can optionally [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) as well in the pipeline if that is what you are after
- #### Script the "join"

  If you are running on a MongoDB instance without [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) support ( and you should not be, since lower than 3.0 has no more official support ) or indeed you actually have a scenario where the "join" would create data per "parent" document which exceeded the BSON limit, then the other option is to "script" the entire join process by executing queries to obtain the "related" data and output it.

  ```
  mongo --quiet --eval '
      db.parent.find().forEach(p =>
        printjson(
          Object.assign(p, {
          children: db.children.find({ parentId: p._id }).toArray()
          })
        )
      )'
  ```

  Or even in the "unwound" or "de-normalized" form:

  ```
  mongo --quiet --eval '
      db.parent.find().forEach(p =>
        db.children.find({ parentId: p._id }).forEach(child =>
          printjson(Object.assign(p,{ child }))
        )
      )'
  ```

### Summary

Bottom line is "MongoDB itself" does not know about "relations", and it really is up to you to provide that detail. Be it in the form of a "view" you can access or by other means of defining the "code" necessary to explicitly state the "terms" of this "relation", because as far as the database itself is concerned this simply does not exist in any other form.

Also just to address a point in comment, if your intention on "export" is just to create a "new collection" then either simply create the "view" or use the [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) aggregation operator:

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "children",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "parentId",
    "as": "children"
  }},
  { "$out": "related_collection" }
])
```

And if you wanted to "alter the parent" with "embedded" data, then loop and use [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/):

```
var batch = [];

db.parent.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "children",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "parentId",
    "as": "children"
  }}
]).forEach(p => {
  batch.push({
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": p._id },
      "update": {
        "$push": { "children": { "$each": p.children } }
      }
    }
  });

  if (batch.length > 1000) {
    db.parent.bulkWrite(batch);
    batch = [];
  })
});

if (batch.length > 0) {
  db.parent.bulkWrite(batch);
  batch = [];
}
```

There simply is no need to "export" merely to create a new collection or alter an existing one. You would do this of course when you want to actually keep the collection as "embedded" data and not need the overhead of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) on every request. But the decision of whether to "embed or reference" is a whole other story.